# How to merge an array of objects keep only properties in the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a working function that merges two arrays of objects by property a1 and a1. The solution was based on answers to some similar questions, however my requirement is to keep only the properties in the original array a1.

How can I adjust this function to return an array of objects containing only the properties in the first array?

Here is a JS fiddle with example data. Note that the output is logged to the console. Also note that the solution must be in vanilla Javascript ES6.

https://jsfiddle.net/dba9r3sf/

```
const a1 = [
 {
    FirstName: "John",
    LastName: "Doe",
    Age: 33,
    Username: "jdoe"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Mary",
    LastName: "Bloom",
    Age: 63,
    Username: "mbloom"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Alex",
    LastName: "Arias",
    Age: 21,
    Username: "aarias"
  }
];

const a2 = [
 {
    FirstName: "Johnathan",
    LastName: "Doe",
    Age: 34,
    Username: "jdoe",
    Job: "Graphic Designer"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Mary-Anne",
    LastName: "Bloom",
    Age: 64,
    Username: "mbloom",
    Job: "Investor"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Alex",
    LastName: "Arias",
    Age: 22,
    Username: "aarias",
    Job: "Student"
  }
];

/**
   * Merge an array of objects by property
   * @param {array} a1 array 1 destination to be merged into
   * @param {array} a2 array 2 source to be merged, overwrites existing values in a1
   * @param {string} prop name of property to match for merge
   * TODO: Set properties that exist on a1 only otherwise ignore
   */
function mergeByProperty(a1, a2, prop) {

    let merged = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
      merged.push({
        ...a1[i],
        ...(a2.find((itmInner) => itmInner[prop] === a1[i][prop]))
      });
    }

    return merged;
}

let result = mergeByProperty(a1, a2, 'Username');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

// Output:
[{"FirstName":"Johnathan","LastName":"Doe","Age":34,"Username":"jdoe","Job":"Graphic Designer"},{"FirstName":"Mary-Anne","LastName":"Bloom","Age":64,"Username":"mbloom","Job":"Investor"},{"FirstName":"Alex","LastName":"Arias","Age":22,"Username":"aarias","Job":"Student"}]

// Desired output (no "Job" property because that does not exist in the first array of objects):
[{"FirstName":"Johnathan","LastName":"Doe","Age":34,"Username":"jdoe"},{"FirstName":"Mary-Anne","LastName":"Bloom","Age":64,"Username":"mbloom},{"FirstName":"Alex","LastName":"Arias","Age":22,"Username":"aarias"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take keys form first array and then select corresponding `key/value` pair form second array

```js
const a1 = [{FirstName: "John",LastName: "Doe",Age: 33,Username: "jdoe"},{FirstName: "Mary",LastName: "Bloom",Age: 63,Username: "mbloom"},{FirstName: "Alex",LastName: "Arias",Age: 21,Username: "aarias"}];
const a2 = [{FirstName: "Johnathan",LastName: "Doe",Age: 34,Username: "jdoe",Job: "Graphic Designer"},{FirstName: "Mary-Anne",LastName: "Bloom",Age: 64,Username: "mbloom",Job: "Investor"},{FirstName: "Alex",LastName: "Arias",Age: 22,Username: "aarias",Job: "Student"}];

function mergeByProperty(a1, a2, prop) {
    let merged = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
      let found = a2.find((itmInner) => itmInner[prop] === a1[i][prop])
      if(found){
        found = Object.keys(a1[0]).reduce((op,inp)=>{
          op[inp] = found[inp]
          return op
        },{})
      }
      merged.push({
        ...a1[i],
        ...found
      });
    }
    return merged;
}

let result = mergeByProperty(a1, a2, 'Username');
console.log((result));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `username` map from `a2` then simply `Array.map` over the `a1` array and `merge` with a custom `merge function` which does nothing more than `Array.reduce` over the keys of `a1` and assigns the values from `a2`:

```js
const a1 = [ { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Age: 33, Username: "jdoe" }, { FirstName: "Mary", LastName: "Bloom", Age: 63, Username: "mbloom" }, { FirstName: "Alex", LastName: "Arias", Age: 21, Username: "aarias" } ];
const a2 = [ { FirstName: "Johnathan", LastName: "Doe", Age: 34, Username: "jdoe", Job: "Graphic Designer" }, { FirstName: "Mary-Anne", LastName: "Bloom", Age: 64, Username: "mbloom", Job: "Investor" }, { FirstName: "Alex", LastName: "Arias", Age: 22, Username: "aarias", Job: "Student" } ];

let obj = a2.reduce((r,c) => (r[c.Username] = c, r), {}) // username map

let merge = (a, b, props) => props.reduce((r,c) => (r[c] = b[c], r), a)

let result = a1.map(x => merge(x, obj[x.Username], Object.keys(x)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const a1 = [
 {
    FirstName: "John",
    LastName: "Doe",
    Age: 33,
    Username: "jdoe"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Mary",
    LastName: "Bloom",
    Age: 63,
    Username: "mbloom"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Alex",
    LastName: "Arias",
    Age: 21,
    Username: "aarias"
  }
];

const a2 = [
 {
    FirstName: "Johnathan",
    LastName: "Doe",
    Age: 34,
    Username: "jdoe",
    Job: "Graphic Designer"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Mary-Anne",
    LastName: "Bloom",
    Age: 64,
    Username: "mbloom",
    Job: "Investor"
  },
  {
    FirstName: "Alex",
    LastName: "Arias",
    Age: 22,
    Username: "aarias",
    Job: "Student"
  }
];

const result = a1.map((obj1, index) => {
  const obj2 = a2[index];
  if (obj2) {
    return Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = obj2[key];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }
  return obj1;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```